# Append a new record to an Access database - VB.NET and ADO.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I wanted to add a new record to an Access database but it gives me this error:

'System.Data.dataRow.Protected Friend Sub New(builder As System.DataRowBuilder)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected Friend'.

In dsNewRow  - in line «Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow»

Dim ds As New DataSet                   'HOLDS a DataSet OBJECT
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter        'HOLDS a DataAdapter OBJECT

Private Sub Button_Add_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Add.Click

```
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow

    dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Ensaios").NewRow()

    dsNewRow.Item("Nº Ensaio") = N_de_Ensaio.Text

    ds.Tables("Nº Ensaio").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

    da.Update(ds, "Nº Ensaio")

    MsgBox("Acrescentado um novo Registo à Base de Dados")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've seen this somewhere before... try removing the New from the DataRow.

I havent personally looked into this much, but I did encounter it a while back!

Hth
Chicken

```
Private Sub Button_Add_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Add.Click
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

'Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Ensaios").NewRow()

dsNewRow.Item("Nº Ensaio") = N_de_Ensaio.Text

ds.Tables("Nº Ensaio").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

da.Update(ds, "Nº Ensaio")

MsgBox("Acrescentado um novo Registo à Base de Dados")

End Sub
```

Comment: Chicken, I've come up with another way to solve the problem. Anyway, thank you.